# How do I set the color of a single meshinstance?

Tags: godot

I have a simple character scene that I instance several times in the main level scene. It's a kinematic body with a meshinstance and a collision shape as children. I've attached the following script to the scene, with the intent that I could easily change the body color of a character in the editor.

```
tool
extends KinematicBody

const char_material = preload("res://Materials/Character_material.tres")
export var body_color: Color setget change_color

func change_color(new_color: Color):
    var new_material = char_material
    new_material.albedo_color = new_color
    $BodyMesh.material_override = new_material
    body_color = new_color
```

This script works as expected, except that when I change the color of one character all characters change color. What's the best way to change the color of only one character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the instances of this KinematicBody are getting the same `char_material`, which you modify in `change_color`. Duplicate the material before modifying it:

```
var new_material := char_material.duplicate()
```